# How to work out how many IP's you've got available on a /29 network mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

This might sound like a stupid question but I would really like to know how I would work out how many IP's I've got available on this network range:

196.44.198.32/29

Can someone explain it to me, what the /29 means and how you calculate it.  The amount of IP's you've got available, the one that would be use to broadcast ect.

Kind regards
Conrad

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work-and-how-do-you-do-it/49836#49836

Comment: Seems a little homeworkish

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For such use you may use a pretty tool named ipcalc

```
Address:   196.44.198.32        11000100.00101100.11000110.00100 000
Netmask:   255.255.255.248 = 29 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111 000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.7              00000000.00000000.00000000.00000 111
=>
Network:   196.44.198.32/29     11000100.00101100.11000110.00100 000
HostMin:   196.44.198.33        11000100.00101100.11000110.00100 001
HostMax:   196.44.198.38        11000100.00101100.11000110.00100 110
Broadcast: 196.44.198.39        11000100.00101100.11000110.00100 111
Hosts/Net: 6                     Class C
```

Also you can use this simple way to calculate :
2^(32-29) - 2 = 6 hosts

Answer (score 19):

To explain what it actually is:

/29 means that 29 of the 32 bits of the address are the netmask, therefore, only 3 bits are available for differentiating between computers.  However, you always lose 2 addresses from the block for broadcast and loopback, so your result is:

```
2**(32-29) - 2 = 2**3 - 2 = 8 - 2 = 6
```

The broadcast would always be the top of the range (setting all of the bits that aren't netmask to '1').

For more details, read up on "CIDR notation"

Comment: This by far the most precise and clear answer. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

/29 means 6 usable addresses:

196.44.198.32 - 196.44.198.39

Typically, 196.44.198.33 would be your gateway.

See this [CIDR calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php).

Comment: .32 would be the network address (which is unusable).  The gateway is whatever you define it to be, but the first usable is a common one, which would be .33 in this case

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. It's a perfectly correct answer.

Comment: As already pointed out, the .32 is the network route so it is unusable; but add also the last as unusable. So, start at .33 to .38; exactly 6 are yours to use.

Answer (score 0):

29 is the number of bits placed to 1 on the netmask in binary. You can make a logical AND with these 1 and your IP to see the network.

Answer (score -4):

or,

```
nmap -sP 196.44.198.32/29
```

Comment: -1 for potentially harmful suggestion. Not everyone has the authority to scan a portion of the network at their workplace. calculate number of available host != scan available host.